# In xfce4, how to set the critical value on the battery level?

Tags: power-management, xfce

In xfce4, xfce4-power-manager handles hibernation or suspend when battery power is critical.

xfce4-power-manager-settings enables one to change the action but not the critical value.

How to set the critical value on the battery level for xfce4-power-manager?

Answer (score 1):

Go into Power manager, and click on Extended --> Advanced Options, and change the value  there.

[image]

For newer versions of XFCE

[image]

Comment: Does "low power" mean "critical" in this context?

Comment: That it does.  I have tested it, and it works similar to that in Windows assuming that you got the "critical value" from there.

Comment: I don't see "Extended" in fact I don't see the whole left side.  Instead, I see tabs "General", "System", "Display", "Security", "Devices"...

Comment: @Michael Please see updated image in the answer.